# Showing that $\ln \frac{1+e^x}{1+e^{-x}} = x$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, algebra-precalculus

Is the below a valid approach?

$$\frac{1+e^x}{1+e^{-x}} = \frac{1+e^x}{1+e^{-x}} \times \frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}}$$

We know that $\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} = \frac{1}{e^x+1}$, so

$$\frac{1+e^x}{1+e^{-x}} \times \frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}} = \frac{1+e^x}{1+e^x} \times \frac{1}{e^{-x}}.$$

So, $\ln \frac{1+e^x}{1+e^{-x}} = \ln \frac{1}{e^{-x}} = - \ln e^{-x} = x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks correct. It becomes a tiny bit simpler if you expand the fraction with $e^x$ instead of expanding with $e^{-x}$:
$$
\frac{1+e^x}{1+e^{-x}}  = \frac{1+e^x}{1+e^{-x}} \frac{e^x}{e^x} = \frac{1+e^x} {e^x+1} e^x = e^x
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct, indeed

$$\log \frac{1+e^x}{1+e^{-x}} = \log (1+e^x)-\log(1+e^{-x})=\\=\log (1+e^x)-\log(1+e^{-x})-\log e^x+\log e^x=\log (1+e^x)-\log(e^x+1)+x=x$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but could you please detail how you go from $-\log(1+e^{-x})-\log e^x+\log e^x$ to $-\log(e^x+1)+x$?

Comment: We are using that $\log A+\log B = \log AB$ and $\log A^n=n\log A$, then we have that $$-\log(1+e^{-x})-\log e^x+\log e^x=-(\log(1+e^{-x})+\log e^x)+x\log e=-\log(1+e^{x})+x$$

Comment: thanks much :) +1

Comment: @Antoine You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score -1):

This looks correct to me but remember that "$\log$" is typically an abbreviation for "$\log_{10}$" in certain contexts such as physics and engineering. It's pretty clear that you are referring to the natural logarithm here, but if you would like there to be zero ambiguity as what you are referring to, then I suggest using the more widespread notation for the natural log given by "$\ln$."

Comment: Actually no. In math, log refers most often to natural log. This is better as a comment than an answer anyway.

Comment: It depends on the context. For example, physicists and engineers typically use "ln." In this example, it's pretty clear he is referring to the natural logarithm. But in other situations it could be more ambiguous. If one is using "$\ln$," then there is zero ambiguity as to what is meant.

Comment: I agree with the comments, but I edited the question (log -> ln) to remove any ambiguity.